# Getting values lower than specified using Con, Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator, con

Expression used in raster calculator (ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop):

```
Con(("%NDVI.tif%"> (-0.05)) & ("%Height_2015.tif%"  >= 16), "%Height_2015.tif%", 0)
```

I want an output raster containing values from 16 and higher, but the output raster contains values from 15.937. Both input rasters are floating point.

I know I've had this problem before... Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like it might be related to the precision of the floats but not sure how to resolve.  Have you tried using '>= 16.000'?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but it didn't do the magic....

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Rerun it, but change the false output from 0 to something like 99999. Then show us a screen grab of the statistics of the output raster.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks @alexGIS ! What kind of statistics do you mean (where can I find it)?

Comment: Right-click on your raster layer, go to Properties, click on the Source tab. In the Property-Value table, scroll down to Statistics.